# How to download the whole source code from the website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i need to download the **HTML** source code of a particular website.website is created with language asp.net.is there is any software .i don't know how to do can any one please help me.Thank you

Comment: i trying to downlad the html code

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is show you a way. I think You mean something like this. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ . You asked question wrong way :) You can get any part of html codes from a web site. And you can use it in your project.

Comment: thank you ya i missed the html

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Asp.Net is a compiled language, what you get in your browser is the output of the compiled dll's that conform the application.

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers, to get the HTML, you can `right click -> 'save as...'` or `right click -> 'show source code' -> right click -> 'save as...'`.

This won't get you the *asp.net* source code, however, just the resulting static page.